# Confused with mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

something about mesh analysis confuses me and I can't find an explainaton anywhere, as you can see on this picture (it's in French, but the schema and formulas should be enough to understand)

[image]

They bascially explain how mesh analysis works, and that's fine and all, I understand the formulas but then I get this exercise :

[image]

And as you can see they just put `I2 = -2A`. Why do we not care about the 12 and 3 resistances ? The exercise is basically the same as the image shown above and in that one we  take both R2 and R3 into account.

Is it because this time we have a current source ? Or because we are on the "edge" on the circuit ?

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance to those who will answer

Comment: There is an excellent video on Youtube by Mathtutor explaining the process, that attempting to replicate the way he explained it would be an insult to them. I will let you judge for yourself. [Mesh current in circuit analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYg8B-ElK0s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the current source and the fact that I2 is the only mesh current in that branch. I2 can't be anything other than -2 amps, so you don't need to write a loop equation for it.

If you swap the current source and the 12 ohm resistor, then you get an extra equation (I2 - I1 = 2 amps) and an extra unknown (the voltage across the current source).